# Exactly Once Semantics KAFKA Possible Claim

Tags: apache-kafka

Regarding Confluent Blog

**Exactly-once Semantics are Possible: Here’s How Kafka Does it**

> Exactly once semantics: even if a producer retries sending a message, it leads to the message being delivered exactly once to the end consumer. Exactly-once semantics is the most desirable guarantee, but also a poorly understood one. This is because it requires a cooperation between the messaging system itself and the application producing and consuming the messages. For instance, if after consuming a message successfully you rewind your Kafka consumer to a previous offset, you will receive all the messages from that offset to the latest one, all over again. **This shows why the messaging system and the client application must cooperate to make exactly-once semantics happen.**

1. My understanding is that title and message of the above conflict. Am I right or not?
2. On my last posting it was stated by the KAFKA folks that Confluent takes care of all these things. So, am I to assume that using Kafka Connect with Confluent means I will get Exactly Once behaviour guaranteed, or not?

Comment: Kafka Connect isn't specific to Confluent... It's up to the Source/Sink Connector to implement offset storage for reading/storing data exactly once... The blog post was **not** calling out Connect, though, rather the Producer/Consumer, and, by extension Kafka Streams API

Comment: I am aware on the Connect and Confluent point. It was simply a related question and valid one. But more importantly do I have a point on the question? I think so... @cricket_007

Comment: It's not clear which connector you are referring to. The HDFS and S3 Sinks claim to have exactly once delivery, and sinks are easier to configure that than sources because you can track the consumed offsets, as with any Kafka consumer client... For JDBC Source, for example, you really only get Primary Key scans or timestamp tracking; if you use Bulk mode, then you are repeatedly scanning the database, and you get duplicates. Plus see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6080

Comment: Also https://youtu.be/CeDivZQvdcs?t=301, and all the other KIPs and whitepapers about it...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding... EOS is possible, but not in all the APIs. And it was made possible by Confluent Engineers working on the core Kafka code.

Comment: So now we are getting to the nitty gritty in that: the text "This shows why the messaging system and the client application must cooperate to make exactly-once semantics happen.". That means that "Exactly-once Semantics are Possible: Here’s How Kafka Does it" is not entirely true. I would need do nothing on the client side if this statement was true. That is to say, from my research, before this paper was published one could implement Exactly Once as well, but it was possibly a harder task than now. @cricket_007

Comment: Indeed as it states poorly understood.

Comment: "Here's how Kafka does it ... *by adding some client properties which be understood by the messaging system and the client applications*. i.e. Kafka isn't *only the brokers*. The clients **must** address the issue as well. Spark and Flink, for example, have external offset storage, and can de-dupe messages on their own using some `distinct` functions.

Comment: @Right, so I am being a little finnicky, but, and but, it proves my point. I certainly read that as well. Anyway, thanks for confirming my understanding, nice weekend. My motto is exactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still work to do on Client side. By their (Confluent's) own admission, the claim that Kafka does it, is a little too optimistic.

cricket_007 alludes to and confirms my point of view where exactly-once semantics are concerned.

Some Confluent Connectors do have guarantees as he points out - albeit that was well understood.